# Initial Load Very Slow Azure Website

Tags: azure, web, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

Initial Loading time is very slow when accessing website deploy in Azure VM. Initial load running in 2+ min.

Resources (i.e. CPU < 2% ) 
Tried various browsers. 
Tried with IP and DNS name results same.
After the website is loaded, the various routes/URLs are accessed almost instantly, but if i reload the main page, or open a new tap and try to access the site again the initial load is running in min
This is not a cold problem for azure websites, i access the site frequently.

The results from curl tests are the following:
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "srinas.com"
    time_namelookup:  0,134
       time_connect:  0,208
    time_appconnect:  0,000
   time_pretransfer:  0,208
      time_redirect:  0,000
 time_starttransfer:  0,298
                    ----------
         time_total:  0,372

The site is running MEAN stack on a VM. Running the same setup locally results in very low initial loading time.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're running this on a Virtual Machine? You mentioned MEAN stack on VM but the question is also tagged [tag:azure-web-sites] which is a website app service. Just wanted to clarify: Is there a piece of this running in Websites?

Comment: No there is no piece of that running on azure-web-sites.  Another clarification: I run it in 'deployment' mode in azure, which means that JS is not minified etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a physical machine. The very initial load is always very slow. The subsequent page loads are fast. However, after some time passes the page load is again slow.

This might be due to two reasons:

1. Application pool recycling
2. Server idle timeout

Try to disable application poll recycling and set the server timeout to 0.

You can do so by following these guides:

1. On your appserver, open IIS Manager
2. In the left pane (Connections), select Application Pools.
3. In the middle pane (Application Pools), select AppPool.
4. In the right pane (Actions), select Edit Application Pool > Recycling… (not the Recycle… task).
5. In the Recycling Conditions window, ensure all checkboxes are cleared (unchecked).
6. Click Next, then Finish.
7. Again in the right pane (Actions), select Edit Application Pool > Advanced Settings…
8. In the Advanced Settings window, under Process Model, set Idle Time-out (minutes) to zero (0).
9. Click OK
10. Back in the left pane (Connections), select Sites.
    Select the Default Web Site
11. In the right pane (Actions), select Manage Web Site > Advanced Settings…
12. In the Advanced Settings window, under Connection Limits, set Connection 13. Time-out to zero (0).
13. Save the setting changes.
14. Restart IIS.